# How to get the current working directory with os library and write a .txt file on it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, python-os

I want to find the current working directory (cwd) with os library and write .txt file on it.

**Something like this:**

```py
import os

data=["somedatahere"]
#get_the_current_directory
#if this_is_the_current_directory:
  new_file=open("a_data.txt", "a")
  new_file.write(data)
  new_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using the `os` library, but the new `pathlib` is more convenient if you are using Python 3.4 or later:

```
import pathlib
data_filename = pathlib.Path(__file__).with_name('a_data.txt')
with open(data_filename, 'a') as file_handle:
    file_handle.write('Hello, world\n')
```

Basically, the `with_name` function said, *"same dir with the script, but with this name"*.

Answer (score 0):

> `import os`

You're halfway there!

The [rest of it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd) is:

```
print(os.getcwd())
```

Of course, you don't need to know that value,
as `a_data.txt` or `./a_data.txt` suffices.

As a side note, you'd be better off closing with a `with` [handler](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers):

```
with open('a_data.txt', 'a') as new_file:
    new_file.write(data)
```

Habitually using a Resource Manager means
never having to say, "sorry, forgot to close it!"

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain right my question. I want to getcwd and write a file on it with `'a'`, and then revalidate the cwd and use `'a'` to write more data in the file.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding, I have to try this `if os.getcwd(): #the rest of the code?`